# can not access the array of an object

Tags: javascript

Below are my javascript code:

```
function A (no ){
    this.no=no;
};
function AController (){
    this.amount =0;
    this.array=[]; 
};
AController.prototype.initArray=function(){

    for(var i=1;i<=this.amount;i++){

        var tem=new A(i) ;
        this.array.push(tem);
    }
};
```

then I execute somewhere

```
var f=new AController();

f.amount=2;
f.initArray();
for(var i=1 ;i<=2;i++){    
   f.array[i].no=0;    
}
```

but it always reports

```
JS: TypeError: f.array[i] is undefined
```

your comment welcome

Comment: Um... are you sure the problem is with the code you have posted? I don't see `f.cardArray` anywhere...

Comment: Ummm nowhere in your code do you use `f.cardArray`

Comment: In addition, as was mentioned in a now-deleted answer, you should start at a `0` index when iterating through arrays - `array[2]` in an array of length 2 will return an error.

Comment: I edited question, f.cardArray should be f.array. sza's answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop from `0`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    f.array[i].no = 0;
}
```

After `push` operations, the array is `[A(1), A(2)]`, so `f.array[2]` will be `undefined`. Since you tried to assign `no` property on the 3rd object in the `array` which is `undefined`, hence you got that error.

Comment: Actually he has filled his array the same way he is reading it, so it should work shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Virus721: not for the last array element.

Comment: @collapsar Ho i just realized he used .push() instead [], but in that case it would have worked.

Comment: @Virus721: yes, it would have.